# Disable OPTIONS requests on localhost with Google Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors

I'm working on a project that use two distinct set, the frontend and the backend.

Everytime I refresh the page, it calls the backend (localhost too) to load the data, but every time, it redo an OPTIONS request to make sur the CORS are set correctly.

Since it's localhost, I'd like to know if there is some possibility to tell Chrome "Don't worry, I know this source, you don't have to check it", or just "Check it, but fast" because everytime (and for a reason I can't determine), an OPTIONS request takes about 13 (!!!!) seconds, everytime I hit refresh, and it's very annoying.

I tried to `--disable-web-security`, but this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally do this at inside our global.asax file if we are having a .Net app
In the global.asax file we grab the options header and replace it with suitable headers
to allow the CORS support.

So in your case too, the support has to be given from the API(Service end) end.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
 "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control",
 "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
 "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
 "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", 
"1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried your method, hoping that Max-Age was the solution, but it doesn't change anything. :/

Comment: Can you please tell me which platform are you trying this? I mean the service is hosted on .Net or some other and which language is the service written in?

Comment: I'm starting to believe the problem is not with this implementation, but the server framework I'm using (Flask, Python) that seems to take time to load the first request ....

Comment: Sorry my friend, I don't know about python, this works for me in .Net platform.

Have you tried this link?

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Cors/1.2.1

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know believe it's located in the frontend because wherever I load the page, it takes a really long time, and once the firs request as loaded (after around 18s !) everything is then fast. The server is never restarted and it's independant of the page I'm loading, even something as simple as a GET or a POST to login is taking a long time!

Comment: Moreover, tested with Firefox, I have absolutely no problems!